# directive to mask in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am building a library for field masking in angular 2+.
I created a directive to mask input with number and money and I have already published the first version in npm.

pardon if this is not the correct place for this post here.

I need to test my library In different browsers and operating systems. So I decided to post here so you can test.

pardon if this type of publication can not exist here.

The link from my library: http://www.renatodev.com.br/

github: https://github.com/renatosistemasvc/soft-angular-mask

**Please report the bugs

Comment: Excellent, +1 for the euro money mask. I'll definitely test it (Y)